# why scope of angular-strap modal do not change in modal.hide?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I need to create a delete confirm modal in angular-strap. this is my code where I am trying to show confirm modal:

```
 $scope.deleteConfirm = function(){
    var delete_scope = $scope.$new(true);
    delete_scope.delete = false ;
    delete_scope.test = "default"; 
    var confModal = $modal({title: 'Confirm', scope:delete_scope, prefixEvent:'conf.event', templateUrl:"ui_component/confirm-mdl.tpl.html", controller:"mdlConfirmCtrl", show:false});
    confModal.$promise.then(confModal.show);
};
```

and this is my hide event handler for this modal:

```
$scope.$on('conf.event.hide.before', function(event, data){
    console.log(data.$scope.test) ;
    if(data.$scope.delete) {
        console.log('deleted') ;
    }
    // optional
    //$scope.$apply();
});
```

and this is my code for **mdlConfirmCtrl** :

```
angular.module("taxeeApp").controller("mdlConfirmCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.toggleFlag = function(){
        console.log($scope.delete) ;
        $scope.delete = !$scope.delete ;
        $scope.test = "value has been changed!!!" ;
        console.log($scope.delete) ;
    } ;
});
```

but when i call toggleFlag function of mdlConfirm Controller and dismiss the modal I get default value of *delete_scope.test* and *delete.delete*.

this is my modal template :

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form name="form" novalidate>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Why do you want to delete ? </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--label><input type="radio" ng-model="reason" value="bored" required /> Bored :( </label>
                <label><input type="radio" ng-model="reason" value="over excited" required /> Over Excited :D </label>
                <label><input type="radio" ng-model="reason" value="exams" required /> Exams :p </label-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleFlag(); $hide() "> Cancel </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleFlag(); $hide() "> Delete </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I get this Change?

Comment: I suggest to crate a plunkr with your pieces of code and that would help faster solve the issue. Looks like here we are missing some parts of the picture: for example where is the event 'conf.event.hide.before' rised? You listen for it, but where is it actually created?

Comment: plunker is very confusing. i try to do this before create question but i could not show modal.

Comment: this event raise when i call $hide function of modal. witch i call in side my modal template. i edit my question and add my modal template to this

Comment: without a plunkr there will be only suppositions of what is wrong. And still after update of the question, there are bits and pieces missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem by changing my delete_scope as following:

```
var delete_scope = $scope.$new(true);
delete_scope.test={delete : false , test :"default"};
```

instate of :

```
var delete_scope = $scope.$new(true);
delete_scope.delete = false ;
delete_scope.test = "default";
```

:).